# Chrome youtube doesn't play/Twitch plays with no sound

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, video, youtube

I have OS X Yosemite, Chrome version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit)

When I open youtube video it loads but I can't play the video. I didn't download any extensions before youtube stopped working correctly (but still there could be an update on extensions currently active which I didn't notice).

- On safari video plays perfect
- Pasting URL on infinitelooper allows me to play the video.
- Incognito mode doesn't play either.
- Chrome flags "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" is in unavailable experiments.

Tried twitch, it plays but with no sound (both in incognito mode and normal). Safari plays fine.
Vimeo doesn't play either.

Comment: To avoid being suggested things you've already tried, please [edit] your post to include those things. For example, have you tried incognito mode? If it works in that, it means an extension has caused the problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome - Settings - Advance Settings - Use hardware acceleration when available - deselect it.

You may have to restart the browser.

Comment: Chrome has started to have this problem on Windows after every reboot. I have to turn acceleration off, restart Chrome (it works then), turn acceleration back on, and restart Chrome again.

Comment: @Chloe Try downloading chrome canary. It'll break more but it may fix this problem. After 3 months you may rechange back to normal chrome

Comment: It's back to not working at all, even if I disable acceleration and restart or if I turn it on. Version 50.0.2661.75 m.

Comment: @Chloe works for Chrome 50.0.2661.86 on Yosemite.

Comment: Try removing `--audio-buffer-size=2048` from the command line start up options for Chrome. That was the cause of my recent problems.

Comment: Okay so this works, but it seems to overheat my macbook a lot. Like, the fan is going much more than before.