# YouTube fails to play or have sound in Chrome, but works in IE

Tags: google-chrome, audio, youtube

YouTube stopped playing in Chrome. If a video does start, if you pause it, you can't restart it. Sound doesn't work. I disabled extensions. I've restarted Chrome. However, videos play with sound in Internet Explorer.

Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m
Windows 8.1

Right click > Copy debug info:

```
{"ns":"yt","el":"detailpage","cpn":"8ioaFVY1WxWh8Ddb","docid":"Zw1Du7OmoU8","ver":2,"referrer":null,"cmt":"0","plid":"AAUenDXrx9RG2hLV","ei":"72PkVbv4LcGF-wW77yc","fmt":"244","fs":"0","rt":"279.649","of":"9iqqk9_SxdexDn4jt--kqg","adformat":null,"content_v":null,"euri":"","subscribed":null,"lact":1,"live":null,"cl":"101619811","mos":0,"osid":null,"state":"8","vm":"CAE","volume":100,"c":"WEB","cver":"html5","cplayer":"UNIPLAYER","cbr":"Chrome","cbrver":"44.0.2403.157","cos":"Windows","cosver":"6.3","hl":"en_US","cr":"US","len":"290","fexp":"3300106,3300130,3300137,3300164,3310699,3312224,3312381,9408710,9409069,9410706,9413031,9415365,9415485,9415531,9416023,9416126,9416729,9417192,9417707,9418153,9418203,9418448,9418537,9419049,9419151,9419326,9419446,9420021","afmt":"251","vct":"0.000","vd":"290.000","vpl":"","vbu":"0.000-223.999,","vpa":false,"vsk":false,"ven":false,"vpr":1,"vrs":4,"vns":2,"vec":null,"lct":"0.000","lsk":false,"lmf":false,"lbw":"371898.301","lhd":"0.127","ltd":"47.704","laa":"itag=251,seg=22,range=3409222-3476225,time=220.0-224.0","lva":"itag=244,seg=41,range=14253926-14586225,time=218.7-224.0","lar":"itag=251,seg=23,range=3576817-3741550,time=230.0-240.0","lvr":"itag=244,seg=49,range=16678284-16964050,time=261.3-266.7","lvh":"r15---sn-ab5l6n7s","lab":"0.000-224.001,","lvb":"0.000-223.999,","ismb":5480000,"debug_videoId":"Zw1Du7OmoU8","gpu":"ANGLE_(AMD_Radeon_HD_7500_Series_Direct3D11_vs_5_0_ps_5_0)","cgr":true,"debug_playbackQuality":"large","debug_date":"Mon Aug 31 2015 10:30:36 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"}
```

These are some errors in the Javascript console of a private browser:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
chrome-extension://eojlgccfgnjlphjnlopmadngcgmmdgpk/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
html5player-new.js:189 'KeyboardEvent.keyLocation' is deprecated. Please use 'KeyboardEvent.location' instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, https://superuser.com/a/884754/130929, even though it was for Mac. I disabled hardware acceleration, restarted Chrome, and it worked. I turned hardware acceleration back on and restarted Chrome and it still worked. I don't know what the problem was.