# Videos won't play in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, video

I can't get videos to play in Chrome. Every other time, I've had to turn off Hardware Acceleration then turn it back on as described in this answer ([Chrome youtube doesn't play/Twitch plays with no sound](https://superuser.com/questions/883775/chrome-youtube-doesnt-play-twitch-plays-with-no-sound/884754#884754)), but now that doesn't even work! I even tried incognito mode. Videos play in VideoLAN and IE.

[image: chrome settings]

Here are some examples of videos that won't play: https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/162334918, https://www.facebook.com/ABC7MorningShow/videos/vb.603158273027819/1198044330205874/

I tried to disable this setting, chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode, but it still won't work.

I tried to disable Pepper Flash, chrome://plugins/, but it still won't work.

[image: pepper flash]

Version 50.0.2661.75 m, Google Chrome is up to date. They release a new version, Version 50.0.2661.87 m, but it's still broken.

Windows 8.1

Comment: So, do you have Pepperflash and Adobe' flash? Which one is enabled now?

Comment: Not sure Flash player should make a difference as both services use HTML5 video player and Flash as a fallback... if you're using Chrome (I'm also using 50.0.2661.87 m) then it should work. Try disabling all third party extensions, reset Chrome and even try backing up/re-creating your Chrome profile.

Comment: @Alexiy Nope, that is the only Flash. I think Chrome disabled NPAPI so external plugins like Flash won't work. Should I try to install Adobe Flash?

Comment: @BigChris I did try it in a private browser session which disables all extensions.

Comment: @Alexiy These are all the plugins installed: 'Widevine Content Decryption Module - Version: 1.4.8.885', 'Chrome PDF Viewer (2 files)', 'Native Client', 'Adobe Flash Player - Version: 21.0.0.216'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove `--audio-buffer-size=2048` from the command line shortcut which launches Chrome and restart it. I undoubtedly had to add that a long time ago in order to fix some other problem with Chrome and videos.

It seems many people had this problem too. I saw many results for different operating systems. Here is one for Windows 10 (even though I have 8.1) https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3ffhkz/choppy_audio_in_google_chrome_after_upgrading_to/

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the fix for chrome but I've found that Google Canary tends to work for me when something's gone wrong in chrome. Here's a download: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: OK the Canary worked, but all of my extensions and bookmarks are missing! Plus all my open tabs! And saved passwords. It's not really much better than using a different browser.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @Chloe you can ``sign in`` into ``chrome`` and all your currently open tabs, saved bookmarks and passwords will be synced to any device you login from. You can also do a manual import of your data. [This](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95418?hl=en) and [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en) may help.